# Efficient data structure or method for interactions in games with worlds of arbitrary size

Tags: c++, game-physics

I've just started making a limited version of Agar.io in WINAPI such that I can experiment with various machine learning styles to train bots to play it. I've always been  interested in bots for games and Agar.io is simple enough to start with (so I thought). However, I've been puzzled over a fairly simple efficiency problem that I'm not sure how to solve. In Agar.io, there is a large world filled with cells, multi-cellular players, viruses and food. Each cell, each game tick, must check if it is eating food, being popped by a virus, or eating or being eaten by another cell. How might I efficiently do this "hit-reg" so that the game will always create the correct result without needlessly scanning dozens of other cells/viruses/food blobs nowhere near enough to the player?

I considered having a global grid structure, where each square has data about which cells etc. are on it, and cells can check only the squares near to them, but because all entities in Agar.io are larger than a single pixel, the overlap issues here looked too fiddly so I disbanded the idea. I'm now stuck through my inexperience :). Can anyone suggest a better design?

Comment: seems you are a victim of premature optimization. Instead of puzzling what would be the most efficient you should implement something, measure it and then improve. Of course you will have to go back and reconsider what you do know, but without doing something you cannot measure and hence you also cannot know what is in-/efficient about it

Comment: You want some sort of spatial-decomposition data structure.  This is an entire field, but maybe start with a quadtree (aka quadtrie).